# Getting default values of any type in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, default-value

Assuming I want to make a function in python that just returns the default value of a given type as a parameter:

```
def PrintDefaultValue(valueType: type):
   print(default(type)) // ?? # <-- how I get that with a type instance
```

For example if I got type of list that It should return an empty list.
If I got a string as a type it should return "".
If I got an integer as a type it should return 0.

Comment: For most built-in types, simply call them: `int() => 0`, `str() => ''`, `list() => []`.

Comment: If you're coming from Rust, Python doesn't have a designated way to achieve this. As mentioned, built-ins typically do this via 0-arity calls to the class, but that's just a weak convention.

Comment: Types don't *have* default values in Python. Those are something that have to be designed into a type system deliberately, and Guido did not make that design decision for Python.

Comment: There's no "default file", or "default asyncio task", or "default database connection", or "default datetime"...

Comment: So, that's seem interesting to me coming from C#, Java / C++ that python does not deal with that default vals at all. So for getting default values, is there a way in python to call the non param constructor through a type instance in order to achieve some kind of default value? .NET C# has got something like Activor.CreateInstance<Type>()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def PrintDefaultValue(valueType: type):
    default_values = defaultdict(
        lambda: None,  # Default factory for unknown types
        {int: 0, float: 0.0, str: "", list: [], dict: {}, bool: False}
    )
    
    default_value = default_values[valueType]
    print(default_value)
```

Comment: Seems like a valid solution to manually define the default vals by myself